# Is it OK to use global variables when they are only used in one file? Are const/constexpr global variables generally considered OK to use?

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand that global variables should be avoided whenever possible for a few reasons:

1. It's hard to debug if a global variable has an invalid value (since every function has access to it)
2. For multiple global variables over multiple files, if there are any dependencies on the global variables (e.g., if you have a = 1; in one file, and extern a; b = a + 1; in another file), the values of these variables will be undefined since we can't know the order of evaluation of these expressions.

Are const or constexpr global variables generally ok to use? Since they can't be ever be written to, they aren't ever affected by the first point, and constexpr global variables are evaluated before runtime by the compiler, so the second point doesn't apply to them. Also, if you only use const variables in the file they are defined in, the second point won't apply to them either.

Also, there are probably some situations where using non-const global variables is really convenient. Assuming they are only used in one file so the order of evaluation of translation units won't matter, is it worth it to use a small amount of global variables when they really simplify your code? (e.g., you won't have to keep passing local variables by reference to various functions from main).

Comment: It's just not worth the risk of developing a bad habit. This question seems very opinion based anyway.

Comment: [Why global variables are evil](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/why-global-variables-are-evil/) and 
[How to prevent 'global variables' in a big project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392146/how-to-prevent-global-variables-in-a-big-project) Learn how to pass what you **require** as a parameter, and if you **require** more than 4-parameters (rough rule-of-thumb) -- it is time to see if you can re-factor your code so you don't need more than 4-parameters.

Comment: I'd say that global constexpr variables are generally OK. For example, if you have the number `42` in few places, it would be clearer to give that number a name and use a descriptive name instead of a number. This question seems like it might be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

const "global" constants are ok - but put them in their own namespace.
The following is an example of the sort of thing that's quite common.
These don't exist in the global namespace, so aren't really global.

```
    namespace ApproximateMathConstants{
      const double pi = 3.0;
      const double e = 2.0;
    }
```

If you want to keep a global variable like in your example to avoid passing so many parameters around, a better option might be to encapsulate some of these parameters into a class object.
Or, turn the functions into member functions/methods for a class, that would have access to member variables.

As well as the problems you already mentioned, global variables can cause many other unforeseen problems later, that will be extremely hard to debug; for example, what would happen if you run your code on more than one thread?

Also, if you have a function that depends on some global variable, then calling the exact same function twice with the exact same inputs will result in different outputs (if not, why have the global at all). While this may be what you want, it can lead to very odd and unexpected behaviour.